# trouble to dysplay listview content

Tags: c#, listview, maui

I work on a MAUI windows desktop app.
I have a problem with a listView.
My datas are loaded correctly after my request in the DB.In this case I have a list of 8 objects.
On the front the listview is sized with 8 slots my listview.count = 8.
But nothing appears in it.
my view :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="FntrAudit.Views.Modal.DocAnliszedModal"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:FntrAudit.Models"
             Title="DocAnliszedModal">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
      
            <VerticalStackLayout>
                <Label Text="Documents analysés" FontSize="Large"></Label>

                <ListView Header="cbcx" ItemsSource="{Binding AnalyzedDocuments}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                           
                                <!-- <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsOk}" /> -->
                            <Label Text="{Binding Intitule}"></Label>
                           
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
               
            </VerticalStackLayout>
          
      
        <Button Text="quit" Clicked="Delete_Clicked"></Button>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

the code behind :

```
using FntrAudit.Data;
using FntrAudit.Models;



namespace FntrAudit.Views.Modal;

public partial class DocAnliszedModal : ContentPage
{
    
    private Audit _audit;
    SqliteDbContext _db = new SqliteDbContext();
    private List<AnalyzedDocument> _analyzedDocuments;
    public List<AnalyzedDocument>AnalyzedDocuments
    {
        get { return _analyzedDocuments; }
        set
        {
            if (_analyzedDocuments != value)
            {
                _analyzedDocuments = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AnalyzedDocuments));

            }

        }
    }

    public DocAnliszedModal(Audit audit)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _audit = audit;       
        LoadAnalyzedDocuments();
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
    private void LoadAnalyzedDocuments()
    {
        AnalyzedDocuments = _db.AnalyzedDocument.ToList();
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AnalyzedDocuments));
    }
    private void Delete_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    }
}
```

the model  :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FntrAudit.Models
{
    public class AnalyzedDocument : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
       private int id;
       private string intitule;
       private bool isOk;
       private int auditId;

       public int AuditId
        {
            get { return auditId; }
            set { auditId = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AuditId)); }
        }

        public int Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Id)); }
        }

        public string Intitule
        {
            get { return intitule; }
            set { intitule = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Intitule)); }
        }
        public bool IsOk
        {
            get { return isOk; }
            set { isOk = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsOk)); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged(string name) =>
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

and the picture
[image]

Thank a lot by advance

Comment: where is the code for `AnalyzedDocument`?

Comment: I have edit with the model

Comment: that looks like it should work.  Are you positive that `AnalyzedDocuments` contains data, and that all the items have their properties populated?  You can also try hardcoding a value in the `Label` to verify that its not a layout problem

Comment: I try to hard code the datas and it's the same : the listview is empty with row equals the count of the object list

Comment: this is what I meant `<Label Text="Some Test Value" />`.  Is that what you did?

Comment: even if I write directly in the view like you wrote.

Comment: then you have a layout problem.  Try setting some height values

Comment: on the verticalStackLayout ?

Comment: No.  The items in the template

Comment: like this ?     
   <Label Text="{Binding Intitule}" HeightRequest="500" WidthRequest="500"></Label>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to customize the appearance of the item in ListView, you may use a [ViewCell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/listview?view=net-maui-8.0#view-cell).

So just add `<ViewCell>` inside the `<DataTemplate>` tag, then you could customize the appearance of item in it.

```
            <ListView Header="cbcx" ItemsSource="{Binding AnalyzedDocuments}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout>
                                 <!-- <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsOk}" /> -->
                                <Label Text="{Binding Intitule}"></Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Then the item will show up.

For more info, you may also refer to [ListView Cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/listview?view=net-maui-8.0#cells)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario, I would highly recommend `Grid` over `VerticalStackLayout`, e.g.

```xml
<ContentPage>
    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*,Auto">
        <Label Text="Documents analysés"/>
        <ListView Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Text="quit"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

This would guarantee:

- The Label will be placed at the top of your ContentPage
- The Button will be placed at the bottom of your ContentPage
- The ListView will fully occupy the center body of your ContentPage
- The ListView scrollbar will intuitively appear should the ListView ItemsSource/ItemTemplate exceed the available screen real-estate in your ContentPage

In comparison, the VerticalStackLayout may give a layout that may be counter-intuitive, and, often resulting in ListView content being clipped with an unexpectant scrollbar behavior.